# How do I use cascading parameters in dotnet 8.0 (Blazor)

Tags: .net-core, blazor, .net-8.0

I am trying to use cascading parameters to my dotnet 8.0 blazor application. I can see the parameters flash on my screen when I load the page but then they disappear. If I try to debug, I can see that during the first load of the page (prerender), the cascading parameters are set properly. The second (server) load of the page has all cascading parameters not set (null).

I followed this guide from Microsoft's official documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/cascading-values-and-parameters?view=aspnetcore-8.0

I can not get the "ThemeInfo" parameter to cascade when the page is server rendered. It only cascades when the page is prerendered, then it disappears.

```cs
@page "/themed-counter"
@using BlazorSample.UIThemeClasses

@rendermode ServerInteractive

<h1>Themed Counter</h1>

<p>Current count: @currentCount</p>

<p>
    <button @onclick="IncrementCount">
        Increment Counter (Unthemed)
    </button>
</p>

<p>
    <button 
        class="btn @(ThemeInfo is not null ? ThemeInfo.ButtonClass : string.Empty)" 
        @onclick="IncrementCount">
        Increment Counter (Themed)
    </button>
</p>

@code {
    private int currentCount = 0;

    [CascadingParameter]
    // this themeinfo is only cascaded properly during prerender
    protected ThemeInfo? ThemeInfo { get; set; } 

    private void IncrementCount()
    {
        currentCount++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You provide no information about `ThemeInfo`, so I'll use the `Daleks` as per the MS Learn documents.

I've set up a Blazor Server Net8 Rc2 project, and configured it as per the article.

This is Blazor Server: here's my app.razor

```cs
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <base href="/" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="app.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="SO77448922.styles.css" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png" />
    <HeadOutlet @rendermode="@RenderMode.InteractiveServer" />
</head>

<body>
    <Routes @rendermode="@RenderMode.InteractiveServer" />
    <script src="_framework/blazor.web.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Here's my `Index` to test your issue.

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<div>
    <pre>Daleks : @(_daleks?.Units.ToString() ?? "No Daleks about")</pre>
</div>

@code {
    [CascadingParameter] private Daleks? _daleks { get; set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"There are {_daleks?.Units ?? 0} Daleks in your vicinity!");
    }
}
```

And the result is:

```cs
There are 789 Daleks in your vicinity!
There are 789 Daleks in your vicinity!
```

So everything works as advertised.

Comment: Sorry I did not reflect this in the code in the question, but this bug only exists on ServerInteractive rendermode (hence the pre-render and server render description in the question)

Comment: See my updated answer, the answer was based on using `ServerInteractive`.  There must be something wrong in how you are you setting `ThemeImnfo`?

Comment: First off thanks. This just saved my ass. Second, why does this fix it? Is it because the `<Routes>` needs to match the `@rendermode`? And if `<Routes>` sets the `@rendermode` to `InteractiveServer`, does  `@rendermode` then need to even be set? TIA

Comment: @DavidThielen - I haven't time to look back into this at the moment, but I think you need to set the render mode above where you have the cascades. To answer your question: no you don't set it on routes and you're running  in Net7-  Server mode.  This mixed mode stuff is getting out of hand [I'm of the very humble opinion that MS made an error in creating the templates as they did].  In my book the mixed mode stuff is principally to provide a path for MS's installed base of Server-Side users to move forward.

Answer (score 0):

It seems a bug,when I tried with a minimal example,it only read root-level cascading values during second load of the page

add the codes in program.cs might solve your issue:

```
builder.Services.AddCascadingValue(sp =>
{
    var themeinfo = new ThemeInfo { ButtonClass = "btn-success" };
    var source = new CascadingValueSource<ThemeInfo>( themeinfo, isFixed: false);
    return source;
});
```

I modified the codes in layout:

```
@code {
    private ThemeInfo theme = new () ;
}
```

Whem I debug:

[image]

After some research and test,the mainlayout component won't be called on second load at all,you may try the codes below in App.razor:

```
<Routes @rendermode="RenderMode.InteractiveServer" />
```

it works without registering CascadingValueSource in service container:

[image]

Comment: I've updated my answer,hopes help